# how to call a method automatically in every seconds using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

In `Spring-boot` project, is there a method that want to make it called every seconds automatically?

And make an `rest-api` to set calling term in same project?

Comment: You want to call the Spring Boot method directly (if it is exposed via @RequestMapping) or you are calling it from your HTML/client side?

Comment: Use schedulers. Check it out [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/).

Comment: @ sSaroj firstly, user set calling period using httpRequest(via exposed via @RequestMapping)
secondly, specific method called in every period that user set

Comment: @ Abdullah Khan i was going to use scheduler but if i use that one can't edit period whenever user want to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use cron expression like @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * *"). In this way, we have a control on minutes, hours, days also. Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQiCjQkM06U&t=96s) to know different possible ways to use cron expression.

Answer (score 14):

Here comes an example.
The `greeting` method will be executed every 5 seconds and it can be called when you visit `/hello` endpoint.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@RestController
public class So47301079 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47301079.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @GetMapping(value="/hello")
    public void greeting() {
        System.out.println("Hello!!!");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks a lot! but there is actually more problem.. Do you have any idea that makes fixedRate dynamically when server is in a runtime?

Comment: It can be parameterized with this setting `@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixedRate.in.milliseconds}")` which reads the value from your configuration.

Comment: Great idea!! Apply that with properties file and update period whenever user try to update the period. So that user can control the period. Have to restart server every time

Comment: Hi, if this answer helps you for your original question, please accept it, thanks!

Comment: @HyungRyuk Hi, I wonder know why you accept my answer and cancel it!